# Custom FirebaseMessagingService is being ignored

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to add a `FirebaseMessagingService` subclass to an Android app so I can receive device tokens, but the service isn't being created.

Here is the service:

```
package com.company.AppName;

import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;

public class AppFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
  private static final String TAG = "AppFbMessagingService";

  public AppFirebaseMessagingService() {
    Log.d(TAG, "created");
  }

  @Override
  public void onNewToken(String token) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + token);
    NativeApp.shared().setDeviceToken(token);
  }
}
```

And my manifest with the service declaration:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="10000" android:versionName="1.0.0" package="com.company.AppName" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="org.apache.cordova.camera.FileProvider">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/camera_provider_paths" />
        </provider>
        <service android:enabled="true" android:name="com.company.AppName.LocationListenerService" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
        <service
            android:name="com.company.AppName.AppFirebaseMessagingService" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="26" />
</manifest>
```

These are the only firebase related logs I see when I start the app:

```
D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping initialization.
    com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
```

Neither of the logs in `AppFirebaseMessagingService` are called. I've tried replacing `android:name="com.company.AppName.AppFirebaseMessagingService"` with `android:name="AppFirebaseMessagingService"` and removing `android:exported="false"`.

Answer (score 0):

Started working when I ran on a real device instead of the emulator. Doesn't make any sense considering it *was* working in the emulator.

Comment: It's possible that your virtual device does not yet have Google play services